# FPDF Automatic cell adjustment

Tags: php, fpdf

How do I make the cell adjust automatically? I'm pulling data from the database and some of them are in paragraph so I used the `Multicell` method so the text wont overflow. This method makes my table longer. Now I'm having a hard time to adjust the cell so that it will fit perfectly.

This is how my pdf looks like now.
[image]

You can clearly see that the color of my cell overlaps and some of the cell's width doesnt match with the title above. Can somebody help me figure this out? Thank you so much.

This is my codes.

```html
<?php

require("con.php");

$sql="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ssh REGEXP '^[^A-Za-z0-9]' ASC, ssh DESC";

$records=mysql_query($sql);
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($records);

require("library/fpdf.php");

$pdf = new PDF('p', 'mm', 'Legal');
$title = 'Storm Surge Warning';
$pdf->SetTitle($title);
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,40);

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetBorders(array('LT', 'LT', 'LT', 'LT', 'TLR'));
$pdf->SetWidths(array(25, 27, 35, 54, 53));
$pdf->SetAligns(array('C', 'C', 'C', 'L', 'L'));

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);

$pdf->Row(array("SS Height",
                "Provinces",
                "Low Lying Coastal Areas in the Municipalities of:",
                "IMPACTS",
                "ADVICE/Actions to Take"), 1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 11);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){

  switch ($row['ssh']) { 
    case '2-3Meters' : 
    $pdf->SetFillColor(191, 143, 0); 
    $pdf->Cell(25, 80, $row['ssh'], 1, 0, 'C', TRUE); 
    break; 
    case  '1-2Meters' : 
    $pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 0); 
    $pdf->Cell(25, 50, $row['ssh'], 1, 0, 'C', FALSE); 
    break; 
    case '<1Meter' : 
    $pdf->SetFillColor(91, 155, 213);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 55, $row['ssh'], 1, 0, 'C', TRUE); 
    break; 

    default : 
    $pdf->Cell(25, 10, $row['ssh'], 1, 1, 'C', FALSE); 
    break; 
    }

  $pdf->Row(array(
  //$row['ssh'],
  $row['provi'],
  $row['muni'],
  $row['impact'],
  $row['advice']), 1);
  }
       
$pdf->SetBorders(array('T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'));
$pdf->Row(array('','','','',''), 1, false, 1);

$pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);

$pdf->OutPut();
?>
```